# Asp.net Page with C# : How to keep a list of checked checkboxes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-ajax

I have multiple checkboxes I've added programatically.

When they're clicked I have a method fire that says, if they are checked add them to a list I've defined, and if they're unchecked remove them from the list.

My problem is that each time I do this, the list seems to be recreated because it becomes empty.

Edit:

A bit of relevant code.

```
    protected void check_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox me = ((CheckBox)sender);
        MenuNode m = ((MySpecialEventArgs)(e)).theVar;
        if (me.Checked == true)
        {
            me.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.AliceBlue;
            checkedIDs.Add(m.ID, m.ID);
        }
        else
        {
            me.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.YellowGreen;
            checkedIDs.Remove(m.ID);
        }


    }

    protected void button_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String checkedMenus = "";
        foreach (int menuID in checkedIDs.Values)
        {
            checkedMenus +="'"+ menuID + "'";
        }
     //Do DB Stuff
    }
```

Comment: Care to share any source code?

Comment: Added some source code. Is there anything else you'd like to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be storing the list in the Session and using a property to save or retrieve it. Please try:

```
protected List<int> CheckedIDs
{
    get
    {
        List<int> checkedIDs = new List<int>();
        if (Session["CheckedIDs"] != null)
        checkedIDs = (List<int>)Session["CheckedIDs"];
        return checkedIDs;
    }
    set
    {
        Session["CheckedIDs"] = value;
    }
}
```

Modify check_Clicked  and button_clicked :

```
protected void check_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox me = ((CheckBox)sender);
    MenuNode m = ((MySpecialEventArgs)(e)).theVar;
    List<int> checkedIDs = CheckedIDs;
    if (me.Checked == true)
    {
        me.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.AliceBlue;
        checkedIDs.Add(m.ID, m.ID);
    }
    else
    {
        me.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.YellowGreen;
        checkedIDs.Remove(m.ID);
    }
    CheckedIDs = checkedIDs;
}

protected void button_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String checkedMenus = "";
    List<int> checkedIDs = CheckedIDs;
    for (int i=0; i <  checkedIDs.Count ; i++)
    {
        checkedMenus +="'"+ checkedIDs[i].ToString() + "'";
    }
    //Do DB Stuff
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your checkbox creation method wrapped in if !Page.IsPostBack ? You shouldn't have to store them in session, if anything I would store then in ViewState instead.